# Access a stopword list from a Solr component code

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm writing a custom Solr component. In the component code I need to use a list of stopwords. I can hard-code the stopword list in the component code:

```
Set<String> stopwords = new HashSet<String>();
stopwords.add("a");
stopwords.add("the");
...
```

Naturally, instead of hard-coding the stopword list, I prefer using a stopword file with which to initialize the `Set<String>` of stopwords. I have created such a stopword file. My questions are:

1. Where should I put the file? (I've found several locations which contain a `stopwords.txt` file.
2. How do I initialize a `Set<String>` of stopwords with the terms in the file? In particular, does Solr provide a mechanism which allows me to get the stopwords stored in the file as a `Set<String>` or a `List<String>`?

Comment: In this context `how` can mean a lot of things.. could you elaborate?

Comment: @zEro: I've added a clarification. Namely, a solution in which I have to open the file and read it is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make your component [ResourceLoaderAware](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/ResourceLoaderAware.html?is-external=true#inform%28org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.ResourceLoader%29).
`ResourceLoaderAware` would provide you `inform` method with an instance of `ResourceLoader` and you can use this to load and read the files.
The files should be hosted in the conf directory, probably.

e.g. code from SynonymFilterFactory.java synonyms is the attribute defined in the schema.xml

```
protected Iterable<String> loadRules( String synonyms, ResourceLoader loader ) {
    List<String> wlist=null;
    try {
      File synonymFile = new File(synonyms);
      if (synonymFile.exists()) {
        wlist = loader.getLines(synonyms);
      } else  {
        List<String> files = StrUtils.splitFileNames(synonyms);
        wlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String file : files) {
          List<String> lines = loader.getLines(file.trim());
          wlist.addAll(lines);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return wlist;
}
```